# How do you read Environment Variables in Debug Azure Function

Tags: azure-functions

I am sure I am missing the obvious and getting to grips with Azure functions.

Question

In debug what do I need to set up in order to read the Enviroment variables from keyVault?

It seems to return null in debug? is there a special settings in local.settings.Json?

thanks

Comment: Hi, any update?:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

local.settings.json? No, what you should do is put the reference to the configuration settings on azure instead of local.settings.json. And you need to give your function app fully access policy to key vault.

Have a look of this doc:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-key-vault-references#granting-your-app-access-to-key-vault

Comment: Hi  thanks for the reply I already did all that and works when running the function  in the cloud as it reads successfully from the key vault but not in debug .

Comment: @developer9969 No, I think your requirement is impossible. The reason is you can not give the local function app an identity. Function app will return the string directly instead of the secret value. By the way, why you don't give the value directly to the local function app? There is no need to do a reference. Key vault is just used for safety on azure.

Comment: happy for any suggestions.Are you saying, dont have these values in the keyvault but hardcode in the function? We dont want these secret available for everyone to see we have to have in the keyvault and all works well apart from debug that returns null.Surely is a common scenario? If I misunderstood you could you post a snippet!

Comment: @developer9969 You just do a test locally, right? Therefore, there are two options: 1. Locally, directly put a non-production environment value in local.settings.json by hard coding. 2. Use remote debug. In this case, the key vault reference is irrelevant to the local local.settings.json(you only need to ensure that the azure function deployed on azure can successfully reference the key vault.).

Comment: @developer9969 In your example, you need an identity based on the local function app and give this identity access to the key vault policy. I think this is impossible. And I think there is no such a mechanism locally to convert references into environment variables, it needs to be converted before it can get the value. Do you mean the key vault value when you get null? How do you set it in local.setting.json? And how do you get it?

Comment: thanks for your time on this one. I am kind of new to azure functions and debugging as you usually do anything else is not as straight forward at times..What you are saying about debugging when using keyvault in function might be impossible but then I would have to remove the usage of the keyvault in a function if I cannot debug the rest of the function that depends on it. I have not used remote debug on azure function (apart from starting the function locally) I need to read /find tutorial on how you debug a function then...

Comment: @developer9969 Have a look of this: https://www.locktar.nl/uncategorized/azure-remote-debugging-manually-in-visual-studio-2017/ The point I want to emphasize is that using the key vault on azure to reference secrets, it is only to ensure security. So I think the key lies in the logic. As long as you think the logic is okay after you hard-code it locally and debug it, you can use the key vault secret in the application on Azure after deploying it to Azure. I don't think it is necessary to use the key vault reference when debugging locally. . .

Comment: you have been of great help on this one